# How can I modify a CardBuilder's Image scale type?

Tags: imageview, google-glass

I am using a `CardBuilder` with the Caption layout – with only one picture at a time. That means I do not really leverage the *Mosaic view*.

Is there any way I can modify that image scale type to show it so that all the picture can be seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible; by design, the mosaic used by `CardBuilder` center-crops images to fill the entire mosaic cell without leaving any borders on the sides.